# Is there a way I can query at run time which Layout folder a given device happens to be using?

Tags: android, layout

I have an app for which I have a multitude of layout folders to accomodate various devices, but I'm finding it very hard to debug because in certain situations, due to the disparate nature of the app, on some devices it will crash because of an ID typo or a Layout type mismatch, but it's really hard for me to track down in which specific XML file the error occurs and the only way I can think of, to simplify, is to find out which layout folder the given device is looking to for its layouts.

Is there some way to get that info at run-time, or am I cursed to calculate which folder it is based on the device specs?

Answer (score 1):

I had a similar problem at one point, and just created an XML layout in numerous layout sizes, with the name of the layout size (e.g. "sw720") as the text in a TextView. I put them all in a utility library, and have a method that inflates it. From the app it's then trivial to determine what layout Android decided to load for you.  It was very helpful when testing on different devices, and while doing orientation changes.

I did normal/large/xlarge/sw600/sw720/w600/w720, etc.

The layout file is just a TextView, and all the layout files are identical except for the android:text= value.  Creating the Android library and doing the layout files only took about an hour, since you write the layout file once and just keep copying it into new layout folders.  The method I mentioned is just a public static String that inflates the layout and returns the TextView's text.

I used this for reference: "Supporting Multiple Screens" http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html

Comment: Thanks. I actually thought of this approach (and I'll +1 for taking the time to answer) but I'm wondering if there's a more native way to get Android to tell me what folder its using.